# Angular - Lazy Load List

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

One of the select drop downs for my application has a huge number of items,to the point it's causing a slight delay on page load.

Currently, I grab the items for the drop down using a basic http call, then simply insert the data into the scope.

Is there a typical approach that is used when dealing with huge lists for drop downs?

Can post code if needs be, but as mentioned it's basically

```
$http.get(myListUrl).then....

$scope.myListItems = response
```

I am also using the Chosen library.

Comment: This sounds like a poor design.  If you really have that many items, you should be paging them.

Answer (score 0):

Great thing about Angular's `$http` is the built-in [cache function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Simply set the `cache` to `true`. This will create a custom service that fetches the the data if it is empty and populates it on success. The next time the service is called it will not call the service but instead retrieve the data from the cache.

```
$http.get(myListUrl, { cache: true}).success(...);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)

```
var cache = $cacheFactory('myCache');
var data = cache.get(someKey);
if (!data) {
   $http.get(url).success(function(result) {
      data = result;
      cache.put(someKey, data);
   });
```

Comment: Already using cache :) Unfortunately does not seem to be helping!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the call to the $http.get in a $timeout to delay it till after page load?